# Suppose that $x^4$ is a prime number. Find all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $x^4$ is a prime number.Find all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$.

Comment: @Dorina: How can $x^4$ be a prime number? Do you mean $x^4-p=0$ for some prime $p$?

Comment: @DennisGulko, I think $x^4$ is an integer, but $x,x^2,x^3$ are not.

Comment: This is basically showing $1,p^{1/4},p^{1/2},p^{3/4}$ is a rational vector space basis of $\Bbb Q(p^{1/4})$.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am missing something, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a degree $4$ extension, and the basis is $1, x, x^2, x^3,$ so the answer is $a=b=c=d=0.$

Answer (score 0):

if $a=0$, then $x$ is a root of a second degree polynomial. Hence $x=p+\sqrt{d}$ for some rationals $p$ and $d$. Hence $x^4=p^4+6p^2d+d^2+4\sqrt{d}p(p^2+d)$. It's easy to see that either $x$ or $x^2$ is an integer (and so $x^4$ is not prime), or $x^4$ is not an integer.

(For the same reason, $x$ can't be the root of a 1 degree polynomial)

Let $a=1$ (without loss of generality), and $p=x^4$

$$0=(x^3+bx^2+cx+d)(x-b)=x^4+(c-b^2)x^2+(d-bc)x-bd$$

Hence

$$x^2(c-b^2)+(d-bc)x+(p-bd)=0$$

So $x$ is the root of a second degree polynomial : it's not possible !

The only remaining solution is $a=b=c=d=0$.

As you can see $x^4$ does not need to be prime. Not square is enough !